# What is wrong with this for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Hi guys I have an array that I'm trying to append to the DOM!
Here is the code:

```
function inputFeedContent(data){
    for(var k=0; k < columns; k++) {
        var col = "<div class='col-1'>";
        for(var j=0; j < data.sample[k].length; j++) {
            col += "<p>"+data.sample[k][j]+"</p>";
        }
        col += "</div>";
        $('.sliding-window').append(col);
    }
}
```

where **columns** = 12.

Problem is I only get five of these:

```
<div class="col-1">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Keep in mind I'm a noob :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the length of the 'data' array?

Comment: And what is the output you want to get?

Comment: Data length = 5. I want to achieve 12 columns <div class="col-1"></div> each containing five <p>Content</p>

Comment: `columns` looks like it could be a magic number?  How does `columns`  get assigned 12?

Comment: I have an other loop that goes through the headers so columns = data.headers.length;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to print each column separately, hence not row after row.
Try this:

```
function inputFeedContent(data) {
    for(var k=0; k < columns; k++) {
     var col = "<div class='col-1'>";
     for(var j=0; j < data.sample.length; j++) {
        col += "<p>"+data.sample[j][k]+"</p>";
     }
     col += "</div>";
     $('.sliding-window').append(col);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `data` does not contain the right number of columns, you'll get errors and it'll stop adding to your page.  You can make sure the columns are initialized properly with something like the following:

```
function inputFeedContent(data){
    var sampleData = data.sample || [];
    for(var k=0; k < columns; k++) {
        var col = "<div class='col-1'>";
        var columnData = sampleData[k] || [];

        for(var j=0; j < columnData.length; j++) {
            col += "<p>"+columnData[j]+"</p>";
        }
        col += "</div>";
        $('.sliding-window').append(col);
    }
}
```

...But likely this case should not be supported to begin with and you should throw an error:

```
function inputFeedContent(data){
    var sampleData = data.sample || [];
    if(sampleData.length != columns){ 
        throw "inputFeedContent:  Sample data does not have the right number of columns.";
    }

    ..//Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your array dont have 12 columns so instead of defining columns as global variable
try this

```
function inputFeedContent(data){
var col=[];
for(var k=0; k < data.sample.length; k++) {

       col.push("<div class='col-1'>");
        for(var j=0; j < data.sample[k].length; j++) {
            col.push("<p>"+data.sample[k][j]+"</p>");
        }
        col.push("</div>");

    }
$('.sliding-window').append(col.join(''));
}
```

I will also suggest you to avoid string concatination as it is not efficient in loop and do dom access once by keeping it outside the loop.